# Table header is not shown using Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, jtable

A table header is not shown using Eclipse. How to solve the problem? Only data coming from the database successfully. So I attached below what I tried.
[image]

This is the code that I used to display the data from the database:

```
void table_load() {
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from registation");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table_1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

table_1 = new JTable();
table_1.setBounds(448, 62, 383, 296);
frmStudentCrud.getContentPane().add(table_1);
```

Comment: What is the type of `table_1`? What's the setup code for those headers and that table?

Comment: table_1 ya sir.....

Comment: i add the table code above

Comment: i went to the model properties of table create the new colums but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> table header is not shown

```
frmStudentCrud.getContentPane().add(table_1);
```

The header is only shown when you add the table to a scroll pane and add the scroll pane to the frame.

Your code should be:

```
//frmStudentCrud.getContentPane().add(table_1);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table_1 );
frmStudentCrud.getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
```

Comment: frmStudentCrud.getContentPane().add(table_1);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table_1 );
  frmStudentCrud.getContentPane().add( scrollPane );   if i add it not show any data

Comment: working sir.  cannot give the custom name of the headers